# Using arbitrary paths in page urls

Tags: plugins, categories, permalinks, paths

I have been looking all over the place and maybe I'm just searching the wrong terminology but I need to be able to allow an end user (completely non-technical) to add an arbitrary path to the url structure of a WordPress page.

Essentially I need a simple way to allow the end user to create a page titled `blah` and put it in the path `/something/here/blah`. I tried to use a plugin that allowed category association with a page but it didn't setup the permalink route with the category/subcategory structure like I expected.

I have seen a number of posts about adding code to insert rewrites, etc but I need these paths to be able to be created at the whim of a non-technical user. I do not have ton of experience with WordPress but I'm a veteran PHP developer so I'm willing to write a plugin (or extend one) but I just need a bit of direction on how best to approach this problem within the WordPress architecture.

Comment: And why can't you create this structure with pages? I mean create page something, then page here and set something as its parent, and then blah, and set here as its parent? Generally you should do this this way in WP.

Comment: On most of the pages, this is what will happen but there are a couple scenarios where there is not a parent page so I was looking for some kind of override. I guess I could just create empty pages for the parent structure...

Comment: There are several filters, `wp_unique_post_slug`, `wp_insert_post_data ` for example you can tie into change the slug, on top of that you can use http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields.